# S3 policy - listing only specific bucket for user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy

I'm new to s3 and policies. I have a simple question:

I can't seem to restrict all my buckets to be visible for a guest user. I would like to have something like this

bucket1 (should not be visible)
bucket2 (should not be visible)
bucket3 (should be visible)

I can restrict access to bucket1 and 2, but I can't prevent them from being shown to the user, which is what I would like to achieve.

Comment: I would agree, except those doesn't work. It's like those answers but it only restricts access, it doesn't actually prevent the buckets from being shown.

Comment: Well, if none of the suggested policies work, then the first answer from Sept 23rd is correct, i.e. this is impossible as of now :)

Comment: This is not a supported configuration.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.